# why react native navigation keep going to NotFound screen?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I just added new Screen, but the react native navigation keep pointing to NotFound on saving a update. Why?

The index navigation would be something like this from expo init (I don't change anything)

```
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
      <Stack.Screen name="NotFound" component={NotFoundScreen} options={{ title: 'Oops!' }} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

And BottomTabNavigator would be something like this

```
<BottomTab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Require"
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: Colors[colorScheme].tint,
        showLabel: false,
      }}
    >
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Require"
        component={RequireNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <TabBarIcon name="ios-bonfire-outline" color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Serve"
        component={ServeNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <TabBarIcon name="ios-grid-outline" color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Publish"
        component={PublishNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <TabBarIcon name="ios-add" color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Chat"
        component={ServeNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <TabBarIcon name="ios-chatbubbles-outline" color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />

      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="About"
        component={AboutNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <TabBarIcon name="ios-information-circle-outline" color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
```

You can read my full code here: https://github.com/dotku/aladdin

Comment: I think the problem is at https://github.com/dotku/aladdin/blob/main/navigation/index.tsx#L19 but I can't figure out what is the issue. You can try to remove the `linking` props on `<NavigationContainer/>`

Comment: Thanks @masbossun, yeah, there is configuration issue on linking, I just modified the configuration file to mach the tab navigation structure.

Comment: glad you found the issue.